# how do we retrieve storage quota of Gmail using apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

i want to retrieve used space and total limitation of Gmail using GAS. i used  "DriveApp.getStorageLimit() , DriveApp.getStorageUsed()"

but i need more clear clarification of such quotas and limits. is it possible to get the quotas of gmail in GAS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you must use the [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) [reporting function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-reports) to access the reporting API and [pull the users Quota](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/userUsageReport/get). You can then check the [GMail/Drive/Total used Quota](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/users-accounts) etc.

I don't believe you can retrieve limits for the actual service, only limits for the scripts service (Such as remaining mails).